# benefits of deploying PCF and TKG on premises

Tags: kubernetes, cloud, pcf

benefits of deploying PCF and TKG on premises - Not sure what would be the benefit of having there cluster on premises..

we will end up having servers and space on premises to have PCF or TKG Cluster deployed ...so what the benefit

Answer (score 0):

Its more of requirements that would decide the underlying infra the I would say.

If you are working for an regulatory organization and got lot of data sources hosted internally - it makes sense to have it on-premises due to obvious reasons. You can have most of the app to move to PaaS and CaaS environments which will be pretty easy to manage and open the connectivity from your deployment network can easily be managed to any required destination endpoints. Standard and strategic CI/CD, monitoring and logging tools can be integrated. Similarly, if you are dealing with the services hosted on other cloud providers like Snowflake etc. it makes more sense to have PCF deployed into AWS infra and develop cloud native apps to access those data sources.

Its not like that you cannot manage the data on-premises with service running on the external cloud infra - its mainly other process like regulatory, security etc that matter.

Usually I have seen hybrid Infra within organization to cater the different requirements.